# How do I convert a Hex value (example: 0xD1) to a unsigned Byte in Java?

Tags: java, hex, arrays, unsigned

I am trying to take hex values and move them into a byte array.  When I do this they are not converted how I need them to be.  Most of them are converted to negative numbers.  For example, after the execution of the C# code "baCommandPDI[0] = 0xD1;", the value of baCommandPDI[0] is "209".  This is what I need.  No matter what I try in Java, the value is "-47".  I need it to be "209" in the byte array, because this byte array is sent out over TCP/IP to some external hardware.  The external hardware cannot interpret -47 as 209.  It must be 209.  I have tried the following code:

int intTemp = 0xD1;  After this line is executed the value of intTemp is 209, great!

int intHexValue = 0xD1 & 0xFF; After this line is executed the value of intHexValue is still 209, I don't understand how, but it ia what it is.

baCommand[0] = (byte) intHexValue; After this line is executed the value of baCommand[0] is -47, bad.  This is not what I want.  Everytime it converts the value to a byte it makes it signed.

Is there any other way I can do this?  Can I use 11010001 and some how assign that value to a byte without making it negative?

Comment: Please add your code so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: the binary value -47 is equivelant as a byte to 209 - it's simply a matter of interpretation. So sending it over TCP/IP shouldn't be a problem. Java does not have unsigned primitives

Comment: All primitves in java are signed. what if you store them in an int?

Comment: I have no code at this point that is worth posting.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, `byte`s are always signed.  But like an unsigned `byte` in another language, 8 bits are still used.  The `byte` representations for `209` (unsigned) and `-47` are the same.

```
1101 0001
```

The only difference is how Java interprets the most significant bit -- `-128` vs. `128` in an unsigned type.  The difference is `256`, which is the difference between `209` and `-47`.  You can send the value as is, because the bit values are the same, only the interpretations of this bit pattern are different.

If you would like to convert the value `-47` to `209` to convince yourself in Java, you can promote the type to a longer primitive type and mask out the last 8 bits.  This line will do this is one line, so you can debug and see that the bits are the same and that the unsigned version is equivalent.

```
int test = baCommandPDI[0] & 0xFF;
```

Printing/debugging `test` will let you see the value `209`.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have a concept of unsigned bytes.

To get 209 from 0xD1, try:

```
0xD1 & 0xFF;
```

Comment: This does not work because I still have to move it into a byte[] and it will make it negative.

Comment: @user3534086 But that doesn't hurt - sending this negatively interpreted byte still sends the byte 209 if interpreted in an unsigned way.

Comment: Its not working on the receiving end.  It doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @user3534086 perhaps the error is on the receiving end then

Comment: The receiving end works fine.  I am able to send it the same data from my PC using C# and it works fine.  I just can't do it from my Android phone because it has to be done in Java, which does not do the Hex to byte conversion the same as C#.